# SASS – looping through map via mixin doesn’t compile CSS

Tags: css, sass

what I have is a simple SASS color map:

```
$brand_col: (
    def: blue,
    mus: red,
    ser: yellow
);
```

The following:

```
@each $brand, $col in $brand_col {
  body.#{$brand} {
    background: $col;
  }
}
```

leads to expected output:

```
body.def { background: blue; }
body.mus { background: red; }
body.ser { background: yellow; }
```

When I try to put the same thing into a mixin like so:

```
$color: null;
@mixin branding {
  @each $brand, $col in $brand_col {
    &.#{$brand} {
      $color: $col;
      @content;
    }
  }
}

.body { @include branding { background: $color; } }
```

I would expect the same output, but nothing is getting compiled at all. I copied the mixin from a sass specific site and don’t fully understand the whole process. Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Ralf

Comment: You can’t use a variable as a property like you are doing: `$color: $col`; what you are trying to do there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive the same result as in your first example, have two options:

**Option 1**

Make a simple non-reusable `mixin`:

```
$brand_col: (
    def: blue,
    mus: red,
    ser: yellow
);

@mixin branding {
    @each $brand, $col in $brand_col {
        &.#{$brand} {
            background: $col;
        }
    }
}

.body {
    @include branding;
}
```

This will compile to:

```
.body.def {
    background: blue;
}
.body.mus {
    background: red;
}
.body.ser {
    background: yellow;
}
```

**Option 2**

Make a reusable `mixin`, so you can pass the color map to apply:

```
$brand_colors: (
    def: blue,
    mus: red,
    ser: yellow
);

@mixin branding($colors) {
    @each $class, $color in $colors {
        &.#{$class} {
            background: $color;
        }
    }
}

.body {
    @include branding($brand_colors);
}

// Latter you can use it to apply the same 'branding' for any other element
div {
    @include branding($brand_colors);
}
```

Will compile to:

```
.body.def {
    background: blue;
}
.body.mus {
    background: red;
}
.body.ser {
    background: yellow;
}

div.def {
    background: blue;
}
div.mus {
    background: red;
}
div.ser {
    background: yellow;
}
```

You could even implement a second parameter to the `mixin` to specify which `css` property you want to apply, with `background` as a default:

```
@mixin branding($colors, $property: background) {
    @each $class, $color in $colors {
        &.#{$class} {
            #{$property}: $color;
        }
    }
}


// Latter you can use it to apply the same 'branding' for any other element and property
h1 {
    @include branding($brand_colors, color);
}
```

Will compile to:

```
h1.def {
    color: blue;
}
h1.mus {
    color: red;
}
h1.ser {
    color: yellow;
}
```

You can find out more about mixins [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, muecas. Your options are all working as I want it to. I will use your last option 3 with even a third parameter opacity. (The construction with $color: $col; was not my invention but copied from a sass-specific site – unfortunately I can’t find the source anymore).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `$color: $col;`? no such property like "null" in CSS, because when you set `$color: null` at top and then trying to set a property `$color: $col;` you actually trying to set like that `null: blue;` this is nothing mean anything to compiler.

I think you no need `@content` directive use here. You should try just following way:

```
$brand_col: (
    def: blue,
    mus: red,
    ser: yellow
);

@mixin branding {
  @each $brand, $col in $brand_col {
    &.#{$brand} {
      background: $col;
    }
  }
}
.body { @include branding(); }
```

Comment: Thanks Hanif, I voted for muecas' answer, because it was more detailed (and a bit earlier), but yours is correct too. As I can only vote for one as the best, I would like to thank you this way.